# React.js: Unable to setState

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Normally in React.js, if I call `this.setState({data: newData})`, `this.state.data` is set to `newData` and the entire component is rendered again.

In my code, I have a search bar. When I press enter, I want to set the search_term to the entered keyword.

```
if (evt.keyCode == 13) {
    this.setState({search_term: keyword})
}
```

The keyword is "dog" and evt.keyCode is 13 directly before this (I printed it out). I am reaching the setState call. However, I am getting an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Can't add property framesToPop, object is not extensible.
```

This is causing the setState call to fail and thus, doesn't set the state of the component or re-render the component to show the new search term on the page (assuming I am printing out search_term inside my render function).

Any ideas on how to debug? What might be happening? I can provide more information if necessary, just let me know! :)

[Edit]

This is the code the console brings me to for framesToPop

```
/**
* Use invariant() to assert state which your program assumes to be true.
*
* Provide sprintf-style format (only %s is supported) and arguments
* to provide information about what broke and what you were
* expecting.
*
* The invariant message will be stripped in production, but the invariant
* will remain to ensure logic does not differ in production.
*/

var invariant = function(condition, format, a, b, c, d, e, f) {
  if ("production" !== "development") {
    if (format === undefined) {
      throw new Error('invariant requires an error message argument');
    }
  }

if (!condition) {
    var error;
    if (format === undefined) {
      error = new Error(
        'Minified exception occurred; use the non-minified dev environment ' +
        'for the full error message and additional helpful warnings.'
      );
    } else {
      var args = [a, b, c, d, e, f];
      var argIndex = 0;
      error = new Error(
        'Invariant Violation: ' +
        format.replace(/%s/g, function() { return args[argIndex++]; })
      );
    }

    error.framesToPop = 1; // we don't care about invariant's own frame
    throw error;
  }
};
```

Comment: I think you need to add some more code context here, what is `framesToPop`, for example?

Comment: Agreed, a bit more context is needed. Like what other calls to `setState` are you making? The `object is not extensible` error is thrown when `Object.preventExtensions(obj)` is called on an object and you then try to add properties to it.

Comment: @limelights `framesToPop` comes from the react.js code. Not mine. I added the code that it brings me to in the error.

Comment: What browser/client are you using? It seems that the client you're using is preventing writing properties on instances of the Error class, which React is relying on. Or, perhaps even worse, the Error class has been replaced with a custom one that calls Object.preventExtensions?

Comment: I am using chrome. I found a solution (guess I had to sleep on it), but I don't think I understand why it was happening in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I gave enough context, so I apologize for that. Somehow my `setState` call was throwing the `framesToPop` error, despite only calling `setState` once. As I said, I was displaying the state using a div in the render function.

```
<div class='search-display'> {this.state.search_term} </div>
```

I was calling some jquery to edit the html that was displaying search term on the website.

```
$(.search-display).modifyDiv()
```

I fixed it by setting the state of search_term to null first.

```
this.setState({search_term: null}, function() { 
    this.updateSearchTerm(evt, keyword)
})
```

Where `this.updateSearchTerm` is the code that does `this.setState({search_term, keyword})`. Not sure why this worked though :(

Comment: A side note but you shouldn't have to use jQuery to update the DOM, that is what react is for in the first place

Comment: I agree with @DanaWoodman - there is no need for you to use JQuery here  react's lifecycle should update the component when a state is updated.